# Return datetime object from database

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, psycopg2

I have a script which connects to a database in order to query it and return a timestamp with time zone variable. I am using psycopg2 to query the database, my command is:

```
db.execute("SELECT timestamp  FROM my_table ")
data = db.fetchone()
```

This itself works correctly but the fetchone() method always returns this timestamp as a tuple.

```
(datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)),)
```

Is there any way to return this variable as a datetime object so i can compare it to the current time using datetime. Otherwise I have to perform some string manipulation on it and its just messy.

Comment: I'm confused about why you need to do any string manipulation. The only string I see in your sample code is your query itself. The first item in your tuple appears to be a proper `datetime` object.

Comment: You `datetime object` is `data[0]`.

Comment: i agree with @Chris, just take the first entry of your tuple t via t[0]

Comment: I'm an idiot, you guys are right. I need more coffee. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
cur.execute('select date from table_name')
for record in cur:
    print(record[0])
```